# selecting previous div which contains specific id

Tags: html, css

I'm using joomla and I have as the following html

```
<div id="ja-footerwrap">
    <div class="moduletable">
        <div id="bottom-slider">
            <!--some contents-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="moduletable">
        <div id="bottom-slider">
            <!--some contents-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="moduletable">

            <!--some contents-->

    </div>
<!--and other divs with classes moduletable------>
</div>
```

I have to select the moduletable and have to apply `display: inline-block;` only to that div which contains with an id of **bottom-slider**. How can I do that?

Comment: are you using jQuery? BTW is not correct to assign the same ID to multiple objects use classes instead

Comment: Since you have the id why not select it directly ? $('#bottom-slider') or document.getElementById()?

Comment: If you are using jQuery you can directly do $('#bottom-slider').css({'display':'inline-block'});

Comment: anyway I can change that id to class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you cannot have multiple DOM objects with the same ID then the first thing is change the markup and transform the `id="bottom-slider"` to `class="bottom-slider"`

Then you can change the parent divs with class `moduletable` *and* `bottom-slider` childrens using jQuery:

```
$('.bottom-slider').parent('.moduletable').css({'display':'inline-block'});
```

Here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9tvcf/

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks. but If I was able to select that with css would be too good but still in css3 this feature is not submitted

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to select the parent div in CSS3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you can directly do

```
$('.bottom-slider').css({'display':'inline-block'});
```

PS: Change id to class.

Comment: but this will not select the moduletable.

Comment: This will apply the display style on his .bottom-slider, not on the parent div (moduletable)

Comment: huh! after editing your answer, you reply me comment of old answer. That's not good.

Answer (score 0):

Using css4 you will be able to do it with pure css too.

```
.module-table! > #bottom-slider {
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately there is no browser support now, neither chrome support this CSS4 selector that BTW would be .module-table! > .bottom-slider

Answer (score 0):

I hope in future like this selector would be selected as this

```
.bottom-slider - .moduletable{/*css here*/}
```

This method would be the best because there is `+` symbol for children selection.

Like as `~` we would hope to be placed `^`

Comment: + is not a child selector it means "next" or "together with"